# Does English have written words for each letter in the alphabet?

Tags: writing, alphabet, letter-names

In Spanish or in Catalan (not sure if also true in other Latin languages) we have a word for each letter in the alphabet. For example, letter "H" is written as "hache", in Spanish or "hac" in Catalan. Can you do that also in English? How would you write the name of "H"?

Comment: I think English has got  all  the words beginning from A to Z

Comment: Of course, just like Spanish. Spelling the letters of the alphabet.